# How to rename Field of an object in java

Tags: java, xml

I have one Java object, to which I'm adding an objectlist.

```
Objects data = new Objects();
        data.setName("E");  

if(!fvalue1.equals("")){

            Objects subObj3 = new Objects();
            subObj3.setField(" OPERATOR", "=");
            subObj3.setField("VALUE1", value1);
            CObjectList cObjList3 = new CObjectList();
            cObjList3.add(subObj3);
            data.setSubObjects("SEL", ckObjList3);

        }

        if(err.length()>0){

            Objects subObj8 = new Objects ();
            subObj8.setField(" OPERATOR", "=");
            subObj8.setField("VALUE1", err);
            CObjectList ckObjList8 = new CObjectList();
            cObjList8.add(subObj8); 
             data.setSubObjects("SEL", cObjList8);      
            //data.setSubObjects("SEL2", cObjList8);
            //data.getField("SEL2").replace("SEL2", "SEL");

        }
```

When I give `"data.setSubObjects("SEL", cObjList8); "`, the first SEL is replaced with the second. But I need both the SEL fields to be there. I have tried naming as SEL2 and then renaming it to SEL. But it doesn't work.

I am trying to create a dynamic xml from this.
Can someone help me to rename SEL2 to SEL?

Comment: What library do you use? What is FQN of `Objects` and `ObjectList`

Comment: Object and ObjectList are 2 predefined classes. I am adding the jar file of that classes in my project, so that it will refer to that classes. I am using struts to develop this project.